# Running question

Tags: running, running-training-plan, hiit

Since a 3 months i started running 3 times a week(about 30 minutes now last few weeks).
Next thing i want to work on endurance and speed and was thinking to do 2 times per week HIIT run(30 minutes) and one longer run building up to an hour in 10 weeks.
Would this be a good idea? Or could it be a recipe to injury?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and comments.

Comment: What is the purpose behind this running plan?

Comment: I think you'd be better off following an established running training program, any reputable running book would have something like this built in. Running is all about staying under the wire of over-training and developing over-use injuries.

Comment: When worried about injuries add swimming. It helps build endurance so you can increase the volume without the risks of a weight-bearing sport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some general rules:
2 factors in a program are intensity and volume (time or miles spent running). Increase only 1 at a time. If youre going to increase from 3 days of running to 4-6, make those days the same intensity as the others for a couple weeks. That way your body adjusts to the increase in VOLUME first.

Next, when you have your volume (we call this building a base) up, you can change one of your days to increase its INTENSITY. I would start with 1 workout day. Make sure you warm up at least (preferably cool down too). You can do interval training. Or you can do a tempo run. It depends on your goals.

It would be safe to also choose a different day (not the day after or before your interval day) to cal your long run. Gradually increase this by a mile or two each week.

This is how you start.